# Compound Poisson Process Expected Exit Time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

It is very well known that expected time for a standard Brownian motion to exit from interval $[a,b]$ (where $a<0$ and $b>0$) is $-ab$. In one of my projects, I wanted to calculate the similar quantity for a compound poisson process. I am not an expert in handling point processes and would be grateful for any help.

Question : $X$ is a compound poisson process starting at position $0$ with arrival rate $\lambda$ and the distribution of jumps as $F(dz)$. What would be the expected time $\tau$ for $X$ to exit $[-a,a]$? Also, what would be the distribution of $X_\tau$?

Comment: The method generally used to find the distribution of the first exit time of a Brownian motion $B(t)$ from $[-a,a]$ relies heavily on the fact that $B(t)$ is a martingale (and hence so too is $B(t)-t^2$). A general compound Poisson process is not so easily analyzed.

Comment: Do you have a particular jump distribution in mind? Seem to recall exponentially distributed jumps were analytically tractable. Certainly mean and variance can be characterised at least in general but not sure about hitting times. Interesting problem though...

Comment: @Math1000: I guess you meant $B^2(t)-t$. Not sure how people tackle Poisson type of processes.

Comment: @Mehness : I would be first interested in Gaussian jump distribution. Do you think it would be tractable? What are the usual methods people use for these kind of problems? Thanks.

Comment: Hi - so to be honest haven't looked at this stuff in a long while and not with Gaussian jumps (exponentials come up a lot in certain applications)- I think Gaussian jumps are a feature of the Merton model (or maybe lognormal, sorry not sure), (Exponentials come up a lot in certain applications).

Comment: [this thesis](https://www.impan.pl/swiat-matematyki/notatki-z-wyklado~/tankov2.pdf) contains the following statement, for what it's worth: "Unfortunately,  it  seems  to  be  impossible  to  determine
the distribution of a crossing time for general L ́evy processes.  The distributions
of  first  hitting  times  are  only  known  in  some  very  special  cases,  such  as  L ́evy
processes  with  bounded  variation,  see  e.g.   Gusak  and  Koralyuk  (1968),  or  in
case of a Brownian motion with constant drift, see e.g.  Harrison (1985)"

Comment: I do have some references lying around (somewhere!) on levy processes - If II find sth useful I'll be sure to post, in the meantime I hope an expert can help you out!

Comment: @chandu1729 It's also important that $\{B_t\}$ is continuous, thus if $τ_a=\inf\{t>0\mid B_t=a\}$, then $B_{τ_a}=a\ \mathrm{a.s.}$ and $P_0(τ_a<∞)=1$. However, for a compound Poisson process, the definition of $τ_a$ has to be modified as $τ_a=\inf\{t>0\mid X_t\geqslant a\}$ for $a>0$ and $X_{τ_a}$ is not almost surely equal to $a$. It seems much more difficult to find the distribution of $X_{τ_a}$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco : True! That's the reason I started a bounty. I don't even know if there is any line of research regarding these kind of problems. Thanks.

Comment: @chandu1729 Indeed I meant $B^2(t)-t$.